# Perform external authentication using python in ejabberd used for chat

Tags: python-2.7, ejabberd

I have ejabberd 17.09 and new to python. I want to perform external authentication using python.
Could you please suggest tutorial links.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are example scripts in several languages in https://www.ejabberd.im/extauth/index.html

Comment: Thank you. I am referring the link - Authenticate Against MySQL with Python but its not working :(